# How Do You Get The Last Access Time Of A File In Epoch In C?

Tags: c, linux, file, time, epoch

I'm trying to get the last access time of a file in epoch format in C but I can't figure out an easy way to do so. I know you can get the last access/last modified time of a file with `stat()` and then using `st_atime` but that returns the time back in a nice human readable format. Is there any way to return the time back in epoch format?

Comment: See the man page for `stat(2)` system call. You'll get the `st_atime` as the integral number of seconds since the epoch.  Don't know how you get that nice human readable format.... but the definition for the `st_atime` is a nice `time_t` typed data.

Answer (score 2):

That's puzzling; the value returned by [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) in `st_atime` is a time in seconds since The Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00).  It is not neatly formatted; you have to dissect it, probably with [`localtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) or [`gmtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html) or one of the re-entrant variants of those functions, and then format it with one of the other time formatting functions ([`ctime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ctime.html), [`asctime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/asctime.html) or, better, [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html)).

Comment: Darn that's what I was afraid of. I was hoping there was a way to avoid dissecting the value returned by stat()

Comment: Your question says you want the time in seconds since the epoch; that's what you get.  You only have to break it down if you want a formatted time.